# Count number of div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi how can I count number of divs I try like this but for some reason It doesn't work.
There is code:
[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/edinpuzic/hMJEy/1851/)

I want to be like this:

```
    There are 1  
    There are 2  
    There are 3
    There are 4...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second `.each()` call isn't recognizing the additional `.multi-field` elements as they are not in the DOM on page load. I'd do something like this:

```
$('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
    var num = 1;
    var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);

    $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
        num++;
      $('.multi-field:first-child', $wrapper)
        .clone(true)
        .appendTo($wrapper)
        .find('span')
        .text('There are ' + num)
        .parent()
        .find('input')
        .val('')
        .focus();
    });

    $('.multi-field .remove-field', $wrapper).click(function() {
        if ($('.multi-field', $wrapper).length > 1)
            $(this).parent('.multi-field').remove();
    }); 
});
```

And update HTML to

```
<form role="form" action="/wohoo" method="POST">
 <label>Stuff</label>
    <div class="multi-field-wrapper">
      <div class="multi-fields">
        <div class="multi-field">
        <span>There are 1</span>
          <input type="text" name="stuff[]">
          <button type="button" class="remove-field">Remove</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <button type="button" class="add-field">Add field</button>
  </div>
</form>
```